# How to scroll to the top of a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

My situation: I have two ListFragments (call them A and B) managed by one Activity which keeps persistent references to both of these Fragments.  When I click a button in Fragment A, I replace that with Fragment B.  The problem starts when I do the following flow.

A -> B -> (scroll) -> (back button) -> B

In that case, when I go back to Fragment B the second time, the previous scroll position is maintained, which I don't want.  Instead, I would like for Fragment B to start with its ListView at the top of its content.

Things I have tried which do nothing:

- Calling `setSelection(0)` in `onActivityCreated`
- Calling `setSelectionAfterHeaderViews()` in `onActivityCreated`
- Calling `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` in `onActivityCreated`

Interestingly, all of these work if I `post` them on a Runnable.  However, when I do that there is a weird flickering the second time I open Fragment B.

So, how do I get Fragment B to automatically scroll to the top each time it is attached to its parent `Activity`?  I feel like there must be something blindingly obvious that I'm missing, but I'm really stumped right now.

Comment: have you setting the selection to position 0 in `onResume()`? :)

Comment: Welp, that was surprisingly easy.  Any idea why this worked?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the right methods, but you're calling them in the wrong place.

I assume you have code that switches between the fragments and you call it when an item is clicked in A. So whenever you do the switch set the scroll to the top, something along these lines:

```
protected void switchList() {
    ListFragment a = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("a");
    ListFragment b = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("b");
    b.getListView().setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(a).show(b).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

And one important note: never keep persistent references to fragments in your activities. Whenever you need a fragment get it from the FragmentManager. This is crucial since on configuration change (like a device rotation, or when your app is suspended and restored) the fragments are recreated, and the reference you kept leads to a 'dead' fragment. Not only is it a major leak, it will also prevent your code from functioning. any change you make to the saved fragment is not reflected on the screen because the screen holds the newly created fragment.

Comment: I don't understand your point about not keeping references to Fragments within an Activity.  I do keep Fragments in the FragmentManager and then retrieve them on rotation.  However, I keep a reference to those Fragments in my activity so that I don't need to constantly call findFragmentByTag whenever I want to do something with those Fragments.  I may have been unclear about that.

Comment: The reference you keep might point to a 'ghost' fragment under some circumstances. If the fragment is recreated and reattached somehow, your activity member still points to the old fragment. In theory you can keep track and update the references. However, depending on the design it can get fairly complicated and bug prone. In my opinion it's an unnecessary risk - `findFragmentByTag()` has practically no overhead, it just iterates a tiny loop and compares short strings, you really shouldn't worry about it.